# How to add a set to a list? (python3x)

Tags: python, list, set, nltk, quotes

I am currently working on semantics using the nltk module. The data that is read uses the following format for each entry in the list:

```
('dog', {'1','2'})
```

So I tried to create a front end for the user to input his data sets. The problem I now face is how to insert the set into the entry.
I tried using the shell:

```
v = []
v.append(('dog',set(['1','2'])))
v
```

Gives me what I want, but somehow my code doesn't replicate that, instead giving me:

```
('dog', '{'1','2'}')
```

With extra brackets on the set.

Here's my code:

```
...
def addpredicate(v):
print('Which predicate would you like to add? \nThe format is p,{\'q\'}...')
v.append(tuple(input().split(',')))
print(v)
choose = input(print('If you would like to add another entry...'))
...
```

Basically, I see that my v.append() thing is most likely wrong, but I don't see how else could I add a set to the list without forcing it like this. I imagine stripping the quotes that come up is also an option, but I can't figure out how to do that either.

Comment: Can you re-[edit] the post to add the correct indentation for your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval` to turn the return value of `input()`, which is a **string**, to actual data structure:

```
import ast

v.append(ast.literal_eval(input()))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should ask the user for the individual tokens, then add them to the set "manually", instead of relying on the user to enter proper Python code (even if they might).

Try this:

```
print('The format is \'p\',{\'q\'}...')
predicate,sets = input().split(',',1)
v.append((predicate, set(sets[1:-1].split(','))))
```